# JS: Removing from local storage / hiding button text

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Evening folks.
Trying to wrap up my to do list and I'm not able to remove items from `localStorage` without either deleting everything from using the wrong key or the contents just re-appearing on page refresh.  A second smaller issue is that button text is merging into the `innerText`, like it's supposed to, but I can't find a way to exclude it  It is currently commented out, if I don't then it breaks the previous entry.  I've left my most recent, and rather poor attempt, below but otherwise, the rest appears to be working.

Not sure if it's ok to attach the whole code, but here it is below.

```
const todoForm = document.querySelector('#todoForm');
const todoList = document.querySelector('#todoList');
let todoItem = document.querySelector('#todoItem');
// const todo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));

// Pull from storage
const savedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
for (let i = 0; i < savedList.length; i++) {
const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo.innerText = savedList[i].item;
const newButton = document.createElement('button');
let itemId = { id: new Date().getTime() };

// newButton.innerText = 'Remove';
newButton.setAttribute('id', itemId.id);
newTodo.isCompleted = savedList[i].isCompleted ? true : false;
if(newTodo.isCompleted) {
    newTodo.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
}
todoList.appendChild(newTodo);
newTodo.appendChild(newButton);

}

// Add Item and Remove Button
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    const newItem = document.querySelector('#todoItem').value;
    const newButton = document.createElement('button');
    let itemId = { id: new Date().getTime() };
    // newButton.innerText = 'Remove';
    newButton.setAttribute('id', itemId.id);
    newTodo.innerText = newItem;
    newTodo.setAttribute('id', itemId.id);
    newTodo.isCompleted = false;
    todoList.appendChild(newTodo);
    newTodo.appendChild(newButton);
    todoForm.reset();

// Save to storage 
    savedList.push({ item: newTodo.innerText, isCompleted: false, id: new Date().getTime() });
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(savedList));

});

// Strike Through Item
todoList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    let clickListItem = e.target;

    if (!clickListItem.isCompleted){
        clickListItem.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        clickListItem.isCompleted = true;
    } else {
        clickListItem.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        clickListItem.isCompleted = false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < savedList.length; i++) {
        if (savedList[i].item === clickListItem.innerText) {
            savedList[i].isCompleted = !savedList[i].isCompleted;
            localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(savedList));
        }
    }
});

// Remove from storage
todoList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    let removeItem = e.target;
    const taskId = e.target.id;
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
        e.target.parentNode.remove();
        removeFunc(taskId);
    }

});

function removeFunc(taskId){
    for (let i = 0; i < savedList.length; i++){
        const key = savedList[i].id;
        if(key === taskId.id){
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
            localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(savedList));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: https://codepen.io/BreadsticksN7/project/editor/ZKQwnJ if it's helpful

Comment: You should post relevant code only. Anyway, at first glance, in remove item function, why don't you use `removeItem` variable?

Comment: I can't seem to isolate what variable to put in for that to function.  Using the entire 'todo' obviously removes the whole thing.  Clicking the remove button and adding a new variable doesn't appear to work, so I'm not doing something correct there.  Tried using the 'removeItem' variable set inside it's event but that didn't appear to remove the item either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see few problems in your code. Here we go.

1. **Remove text reappears** because on adding an item, you create todo object with item value set to newTodo.innerText, if you check your saved value in the localstorage it holds extra **Remove** in it, that's because `innerText` gets the text of elements under `newTodo` (in our case we have a button in there). As a fix, you just need to set the actual value from the `textbox` and not the innerText. You already have that stored in a variable called `newItem`

And yes, as like @cfinn16 pointed it out, the id we save here would be in `number` format, when you compare the id from `remove` button attribute with the id from the `savedList` array you will see a mismatch. As a resolution, you can convert getTime().toString().

```
savedList.push({ item: newTodo.innerText, isCompleted: false, id: new Date().getTime() });
```

2. **Deleting an item**, not actually removing the item from both in-memory array i.e `savedList` or from the localStorage. All we want to do it, just get the taskId, filter/remove items from `savedList` then replace it in the `localStorage` with same key. But on loading each todoItems on page refresh, you set new date as the value to each todoItems but that should be the value from the localstorage itself.

```
let itemId = { id: new Date().getTime() };
```

3. **Strikethrough an item**, has a similar problem. Here you are trying to find clicked item from the array using text instead we can use the id itself.

```
for (let i = 0; i < savedList.length; i++) {
        if (savedList[i].item === clickListItem.innerText) {
            savedList[i].isCompleted = !savedList[i].isCompleted;
            localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(savedList));
        }
    }
```

**Solution:**
https://codepen.io/renishb10/project/editor/ANyqqo

Let me know if you've any questions.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess looking at this would be the that, since the IDs are being defined by `Date.getTime()` being called at two different times, that those IDs are not the same. I would suggest that, when you push to `savedList` at the end of the function to add an item, that you set `id` as `newItem.id`, like you for the item name, rather than calling `getTime()` again

Comment: No luck -- I think my remove function when it does it's index and then remove is where my hang up is, as it doesn't strike the item from `localStorage` when you pull that from console.  A new ID is written at the time of creation, when it's removed, the ID is still present.  I'll look at it more tomorrow, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from Renish, I've modified to include the follow and posting it here so it may help anyone else.

```
// Save to storage 
    savedList.push({ item: newItem, isCompleted: false, id: new Date().getTime().toString() });
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(savedList));
```

Changed the `new Date()` to a string.  As both Renish and cfinn pointed out I had mismatch `.id`.  Changing `newTodo` to `newItem` go around my `innerText` from the button being carried over.

```
// Pull from Storage
newButton.innerText = 'Remove';
newButton.setAttribute('id', savedList[i].id);
```

Modified my pull from storage code to reflect the new button `.id`.

```
function removeFunc(taskId){
    splicedList = savedList.filter(l => l.id != taskId)
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(splicedList));
    }
```

Used a filter instead to find the items to remove, based on the `.id`.
Github of the full modified code:
https://github.com/BreadsticksN7/collections/blob/20b679fc704d05af5576faa3963f676c0bd2665e/todolist.js

Thanks to everyone and their assistance.